# Error when using the command line terminal to connect to the Azure MySQL server

Tags: mysql, azure, request, database-connection

I'm using the command line prompt on my Windows computer to connect to my Azure MySQL server.

```
hostname=flashguard.mysql.database.azure.com 
username=damiboyflashguard123
port=3306
```

I entered following on my cmd

```
    mysql -h flashguard.mysql.database.azure.com  -P 3306 -u damiboyflashguard123 -p
```

and entered the password. Then I'm getting following error,

```
    ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 
    'flashguard.mysql.database.azure.com:3306' (10060)
```

By the way I checked my firewall settings, and it shows firewall is approving on 3306 port requests as follows.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed MySQL client in my local machine and tried connecting to Azure mySQL client via command line terminal and was connected successfully:-

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can’t connect to MySQL server on
> ‘[flashguard.mysql.database.azure.com:3306](http://flashguard.mysql.database.azure.com:3306)’ (10060)

Make sure your MySQL server name with username and password does not have any syntax missing or spelling errors. **Add your local machine’s IP to the allowed list of Azure MySQL servers like below:-**

[image]

Make sure your MySQL server is in a **ready state** and also try to **connect** to your **MySQL server** from your **Azure Portal** to **check** the **connectivity.**

Verify your **connecting string** from Azure Portal like below:-

[image]

I ran the above command in my local machine’s command line terminal and I got connected to the azure MySQL server successfully like below:-

```bash
mysql -h server-name.mysql.database.azure.com -u xxxxconuser -p xxxxxxxxxn@123
```

Output:-

[image]

When I removed the Client IP from the azure MySQL Networking tab, I got the same error code as yours, refer below:-

[image]

Error:-

[image]

Verify if you’re connected to any VPN that is restricting you from connecting to the MySQL server on Azure.